# Set default Tab selected for Tab panel for GXT

Tags: gwt, gxt

I have a application written in GXT. There are three tabs such as: One, Two, Three for example. For each tab, it is also a TabPanel, under each of One, Two, Three there are A, B and C.

One(A, B, C), Two(A, B, C), Three(A, B, C), I want to add a feature only for Two which is: **A is the default tab view when you select Two.**

It is OK when the application is first load. However, if you select B under Two, then select One or Three, then you click Two again, A is not default tab selected, B is default (I don't want the remember last select function)

Anyone knows how to implement that? The class for Two tab panel is very simple like:

```
twoTabPanel.add(aTab);
twoTabPanel.add(bTab);
twoTabPanel.add(cTab);
```

What is the method for TabPanel or how to implement this?

I tried the `twoTabPanel.setAutoSelect(true)`, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if it could work in your case but have you tried to make your components statefull (false by default). see http://www.sencha.com/gxtdocs/#com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.Component setStateFull

Remember that statefull components need a defined id (component.setId())

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which GXT version you are using. I am still using 2.x

Autoselect means, that the first tab is shown when the tab panel is displayed.
So if you select `two` the first time the tab `A` should be displayed. Thats all what autoselect means. 
If you select `two.B`, switch to `one` and then back to `two` again, `b` will be displayed because that was the state when you left `two`.

You need to add an Listener to the `com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.event.Events#Select` event and select `two.A` by hand.